# Is there a portable VPN client that actually works?

Tags: vpn, portable

I have tried ultrasurf and it no longer works. What's a VPN client that is portable and still works? HTTPS would be nice, however it's not *needed*...

I don't have admin on the computers I'll use this on, so any VPN that doesn't require them will be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "it no longer works"?

Comment: @Ramhound It used to say "Connected to server (server)". Now it just says "Unable to connect to server". Also, I just checked their website and it's down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the openVPN portable (from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ovpnp/)) and a portable browser installed on a portable USB thumb drive. I have read that this can get around any logging.

Finding a decent VPN service that is free, (like ultrasurf was), is difficult to near impossible. If it's vital that you have a VPN, I recommend you think about investing in a premium VPN service.

Sites that block anonimizers (ultrasurf, hotspot shield, etc...) generally don't touch premium services (in my experience). If you use one a lot, you'll find it's a worthy investment, (so much faster and stable), and it doesn't cost that much.

I myself use [AceVPN](https://my.acevpn.com/c/53/VPN) and am incredibly satisfied with it. You will need VPN service account details to use openVPN, so it's probably best you start shopping around for a service.

As for free service alternatives similar to Ultrasurf, I'm afraid I do not know of any.